# AWS - CDK - What is the CDK construct to enable 'Encryption in transit' for lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-context

I could not find any option in CDK to enable '**Encrypt in transit**' configuration for lambda environment variables.

[image: Lambda Environment Variable Configuration]

Does anyone know how to achieve this.
Any help/pointers is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Horizon

Comment: Do you know what that setting actually does? It just lets you encrypt each environment variable with a CMK, you can (and probably need to) just do that "by hand".

Comment: Yes, I know what that setting does and can be set manually, but we don't do anything manually and have automatated everything using CDK (Infrastructure as code).

Comment: That is not what I meant - you can / should? just encrypt each environment variable explicitly in the CDK. The flag in the UI may only be there for simplicity of use for and end user.